# Shouldn't Android OS survive app crash?

Tags: android, linux, kernel

I noticed, that some apps would not just crash it self, they can also crash operating system (android), causing reboot. This is especially true for Skype.

My question, shouldn't OS survive app crash? In desktop environment, unless there is some faulty kernel module, normal app/processes couldn't crash OS. They are simply terminated (with optional core dump).

Is version of Linux kernel that is used in Android different from vanilla kernel in that regard? Or is it, that Android applications are allowed to install and load kernel modules?

Comment: Android uses the standard Linux kernel with Google's extensions.  It is also built configured for a particular platform and uses device drivers for that platform.  Apps should not crash the kernel.  It is likely one or more kernel-mode defects that is causing it to crash and reboot.

Comment: Are apps allowed to install and load their own kernel modules?

Comment: Drivers can be installed with apps.  Note that unlike apps, device drivers are platform-dependent.  Before installing, the framework will notify you of what permissions it is requesting.  I don't believe an app can just install a driver without permission.